# How to make someone need a role to use a command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot and I want know how to make someone need a required role to use a command.

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
async def test(ctx):
if commands.has_role("| Premium |"):
    msg = ["test", "test2"]
    await bot.send_message(ctx.message.author,                                              
    random.choice(msg))
```

Please show me the correct way to do this because if commands.has_role("| Premium |"): is not right

Comment: Uh... didn't this exact question get flagged for being too broad this morning? Deleting and reposting your questions when they get closed will only serve to get your account marked as a spammer and blocked from asking questions.

Comment: @squaswin i flagged my own post lmao

Comment: @squaswin and I changed it and added example program... so it is not as broad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a check based on the names of the user's roles, use the [commands.has_role()](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/ext/commands/core.py#L779) or [commands.has_any_role()](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/ext/commands/core.py#L806) decorators.

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Premium")
async def test():
    pass
```

Comment: how would I add an error message after I created what I want them to be able to do if they have the perms

Comment: Yours works perfect but I need to know how to make an error message for it @squaswin

Comment: I am not a ext user, but it looks like you can create a event for [on_command_error](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/ext/commands/bot.py#L286) and check for instances of [CheckFailure](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/ext/commands/errors.py#L92)

Comment: I have no clue because like there is nothing anywhere that shows you explicitly how to set up the event for a check failure @squaswin

Comment: How would I make an on_error event for a checkfailure